# R/Rstudio set browser to chrome

Tags: r, rstudio

I am using Rstudio and would like the help pages to open in the browser. I prefer it to Rstudio's help window (can search, zoom etc...).
If I type `options(browser = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe")` then it works and now help pages open in chrome. But if I put this option in the R_PROFILE file, then R does not take on the startup for some reason. And when I get the option `browser` it gives:

```
> getOption("browser")
function (url) 
{
    .Call("rs_browseURL", url)
}
<environment: 0x0000000010598258>
```

Would anyone know why I get that?

Comment: You are looking for .Rprofile. https://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html

Comment: .Rprofile is for R_PROFILE_USER environment variable.
Rprofile.site is for the R_PROFILE.
I have R_PROFILE set to my Rprofile.xxx file in which I have the options. But I haven't customized the R_PROFILE_USER  file. I tried with that - but I still didn't work.

Comment: Changing browser in `.First` has no effect... Weird.